# Triangular scheme in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

I want to make a scheme similar to this in LaTeX:

[image: Triangular scheme]

I can't really find how I can make something similar. I have heard of tikz, but have never used it. I suppose that it would be helpful. Basically I need to align the text, and draw arrows between them. However, I have no idea where to start (can I do this with `align` and then use `tikz` to draw over it or do I need to do the alignment in `tikz`?).

I don't expect code that I can copy-paste, but some pointers to some helpful commands would suffice.

Comment: Welcome! The Tik*k*Z manual begins with nice tutorials which should get you started. You could at least post an example with the content of the diagram i.e. the text.

Comment: @cfr actually the text is the same as in the example (it is a scheme to show the computation of the B-spline basis functions). I was hoping that I wouldn't need to read the whole introduction to tikz ;)

Comment: The point is that you could provide the content in a form people could copy-paste rather than making people create it by copying from an image.

Comment: Ah, point taken. To be honest I didn't really expect such a ready-to-use answer, more something along the lines of: "you can do this with the <...> command in the <...> package".

Comment: Though not exactly the same, it is very similar to this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247177/generate-tikz-tree-from-filecontents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain this either with `pstricks` or with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt, arrowinset=0.12, linecolor=blue, arrows=->, nodesep=2pt}
\[
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=5ex,  colsep=1cm,  mnode=R]
    %%% Nodes
 & & & N_{i, 1}\mathrlap{\equiv 1}\\
  &  &  N_{i-1, 2} &  N_{i, 2}\\
  & N_{i-2, 3} &  N_{i-1, 3} &  N_{i, 3}\\
  N_{i-3, 4}& N_{i-2, 4} &  N_{i-1,4} &  N_{i,4}
%%% Horizontal arrows
    \ncline{1,4}{2,3} \ncline{1,4}{2,4}
    \ncline{2,3}{3,2} \ncline{2,3}{3,3} \ncline{2,4}{3,3}\ncline{2,4}{3,4}
    \ncline{3,2}{4,1} \ncline{3,2}{4,2}\ncline{3,3}{4,2} \ncline{3,3}{4,3}\ncline{3,4}{4,3}\ncline{3,4}{4,4}
  \end{psmatrix} \]


  \vskip 1cm

  \[ \tikzcdset{arrows={-Stealth, blue}}
    \begin{tikzcd}
     & & & N_{i, 1}\mathrlap{\equiv 1}\dlar\dar\\
      &  &  N_{i-1, 2}\dlar\dar &  N_{i, 2}\dlar\dar\\
      & N_{i-2, 3}\dlar\dar &  N_{i-1, 3}\dlar\dar &  N_{i, 3}\dlar\dar\\
      N_{i-3, 4}& N_{i-2, 4} &  N_{i-1,4} &  N_{i,4}
    \end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathrlap{{}\equiv1}`, in order to get the spacing right

Comment: Dear @Ruben, if this is the answer you think is the most appropriate, then you should also mark it as an "Accepted answer".

Comment: I wanted to try the answer first (the tikz version works fine, I can't get pstricks to show anything).

Comment: @Ruben:To make the pstricks code work with `pdflatex`, you have to add the parameter `--enable-write18` if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` for TeX Live or MacTeX. Alternatively, you can remove  `auto-pst-pdf` and compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: @Bernard I got an error message about enable-write-18. I then followed the accepted answer on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation. After that, I can compile without errors, but no diagram shows up.

Comment: Strange… What did the error message say?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for my late reply. I don't know, I can't see it anymore. I have a new laptop now though, and the pstricks version still doesn't show up (on a fresh installation of MiKTeX).

Comment: Are pstricks, pst-node and auto-pst-pdf installed? In a basic installation, they're not installed by default.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use TikZ `graphdrawing` to have it all connected and placed automatically.  This needs LuaLaTeX.

*N.B.:* One has to name the node containing the `\equiv` (here with `a`).  Otherwise one is greeted with a rather cryptic

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\equiv
```

I chose the `tree layout` for the graph but other layouts are easily possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout, math nodes, edge={blue,-stealth}]
  {
    a / N_{i, 1} \equiv 1 -> {
      N_{i-1, 2} -> {
        N_{i-2, 3} -> { N_{i-3, 4}, N_{i-2, 4} },
        N_{i-1, 3} -> { N_{i-2, 4}, N_{i-1,4} }
      },
      N_{i, 2} -> {
        N_{i-1, 3},
        N_{i, 3} -> { N_{i-1,4}, N_{i,4} }
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could note that this requires `lualatex`. (You do get a fairly clear error message if you try with `pdflatex`, but worth mentioning.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Noted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend this particularly because it is not a tree, but it can be drawn with Forest more-or-less automatically, if desired.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  declare count register=thing,
  thing'=0,
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge={-Stealth, draw=blue!50!cyan},
    math content,
    tier/.option=level,
  },
  label={right:$=1$},
  where n'=1{
    calign with current edge,
  }{},
  before typesetting nodes={
    for nodewalk={
      r,
      while nodewalk valid={l}{l}
    }{
      content/.process={Ow+nw}{level}{#1+1}{\text{N}_{i,#1}}
    },
    for nodewalk={
      fake=r,
      while nodewalk valid={1}{
        thing'+=1,
        1,
        for tree={
          content/.process={Ow+nRw2}{level}{#1+1}{thing}{\text{N}_{i-#2,#1}}
        },
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={l}{
            tikz+/.process={Ow}{edge}{\path [#1] (!next on tier.parent anchor) -- (!l.child anchor);},
            l
          }
        }{}
      }
    }{},
  },
  [
    [
      [
        [
          []
          []
        ]
        [
          []
        ]
      ]
      [
        [
          []
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        [
          []
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest solution]

**Note:** code edited to reflect the bugfix for Forest 2.1. The version above works with version 2.1.2. If you have an earlier version of Forest, you will need to update in order to use the above code.

Comment: has discovered a Forest bug while working on this solution. `while nodewalk valid` (and other loops) introduce unnecessary hash doubling. The bug is already fixed: the bugfix release (v2.1.2) will be available on CTAN in the beginning of the next week.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Updated.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution, this time using the `Xy-pic` package. The advantage of this package is the matrix-like structure of the environment and the few lines to code it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
% the \ar command stands for "arrow"; the @ is the syntax to put options to the arrows in brackets (in this case, color blue), and the last bracket is the direction: d stands for "down", l for "left", dl for "down left"
    & & & N_{i,1} \equiv 1 \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d]\\
    & & N_{i-1,2} \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d] & N_{i,2} \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d]\\
    & N_{i-2,3} \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d] & N_{i-1,3} \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d] & N_{i,3} \ar@[blue][dl] \ar@[blue][d]\\
    N_{i-3,4} & N_{i-2,4} & N_{i-1,4} & N_{i,4}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: triangular scheme]

Answer (score 3):

Here I use a `\Shortstack`.  EDIT: colored arrows added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\stackMath
\newcommand\undarrow{{\color{blue}%
  \kern15pt
  \raisebox{-.5ex}{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{-45}{\scalebox{1}[1.414]{$\downarrow$}}}
  \kern2pt\downarrow\,}}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\setstackgap{S}{4pt}
\newcommand\schemeunit[3][-]{\stackunder{N\rlap{$_{i#1#2,#3}$}}{\undarrow}}
\newcommand\schemeUnit[3][-]{%
  \stackunder[0pt]{N\rlap{$_{i#1#2,#3}$}}{\smash{\phantom{\undarrow}}}}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{%
  \schemeunit[]{}{1}
  \schemeunit{1}{2}\schemeunit[]{}{2}
  \schemeunit{2}{3}\schemeunit{1}{3}\schemeunit[]{}{3}
  \schemeUnit{3}{4}\schemeUnit{2}{4}\schemeUnit{1}{4}\schemeUnit[]{}{4}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    u = -14mm;
    R = 5;
    path e; e = superellipse(13right,8up,13left,8down,0.78);
    for i=1 upto R:
        for j=1 upto i:
            if (i=1) and (j=1):
                label("$N_{i,1}\mathrlap{{}\equiv1}$", (u,u));
            else:
                label("$N_{i" if j>1: & "-" & decimal (j-1) fi & "," & decimal i & "}$", (j*u, i*u));
            fi
            if i<R:
                drawoptions(withcolor .4[blue,white]);
                drawarrow (j*u,i*u) -- (j*u,   i*u+u) cutbefore e shifted (j*u,i*u) cutafter e shifted (j*u,   i*u+u);
                drawarrow (j*u,i*u) -- (j*u+u, i*u+u) cutbefore e shifted (j*u,i*u) cutafter e shifted (j*u+u, i*u+u);
                drawoptions();
            fi
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```